# How to compute the correct pointer difference in LLVM C++ API for initializing a global variable?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

Assume I have two pointers into a global array, both represented as "address of the array plus some offset." What is the correct approach to compute the pointer difference so that it can be used to initialize a global variable?

**Update:**  I also want the pointer difference as a compile-time constant if two pointers point into a local array or to members of the same struct.

In my initial attempt, I used `CreatePtrDiff` and checked if a dynamic cast to `llvm::Constant` or `llvm::ConstantExpr` is possible. However, even when `pointer1` equals `pointer2`, the dynamic cast fails. Here's the code snippet:

```cpp
auto diff =  llvmBuilder->CreatePtrDiff(llvmType, pointer1, pointer2);
if (llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::ConstantExpr>(diff)) {
    std::cerr << "diff is constant\n";
} else {
    std::cerr << "diff is NOT constant\n";
}
```

In my subsequent attempt, I used `CreateSub`, and it seems to work. Of course, this means I have to divide the difference afterward by the size of the element type. Is this the preferred way?

```cpp
auto diff =  llvmBuilder->CreateSub(pointer1, pointer2);
if (llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::ConstantExpr>(diff)) {
    std::cerr << "diff is constant\n";
} else {
    std::cerr << "diff is NOT constant\n";
}
```

Furthermore, I want to ensure that both pointers are pointing to the same object. I came across `llvm::IsConstantOffsetFromGlobal` in [ConstantFolding.h](https://llvm.org/doxygen/ConstantFolding_8h.html), which sounds like it provides what I am looking for. However, I couldn't find examples or explanations for these functions. Can someone provide guidance or point me in the right direction?

Edit: This seems to work

```cpp
    auto cp1 = llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::Constant>(pointer1);
    auto cp2 = llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::Constant>(pointer2);
    llvm::GlobalValue *gv1 = nullptr, *gv2 = nullptr;
    llvm::APInt gv1Offset, gv2Offset;
    auto dl = llvmModule->getDataLayout();
    if (cp1 && llvm::IsConstantOffsetFromGlobal(cp1, gv1, gv1Offset, dl)) {
        std::cerr << "pointer1 is constant offset from global\n";
    }
    if (cp2 && llvm::IsConstantOffsetFromGlobal(cp2, gv2, gv2Offset, dl)) {
        std::cerr << "pointer2 is constant offset from global\n";
    }
    if (gv1  && gv1 == gv2) {
        std::cerr << "pointer1 and pointer2 point into same object\n";
    } else {
        std::cerr << "pointer1 and pointer2 point into different objects\n";
    }
```

And also this:

```cpp
    auto ptrDiff = llvmBuilder->CreatePtrDiff(llvmType, pointer1, pointer2);
    auto ptrDiffInst = llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::Instruction>(ptrDiff);
    if (ptrDiffInst && llvm::ConstantFoldInstruction(ptrDiffInst, llvmModule->getDataLayout())) {
        std::cerr << "ConstantFoldInstruction: ok\n";
    } else {
        std::cerr << "ConstantFoldInstruction: failed\n";
    }
```

The last code snippet solves my problem of computing the pointer difference at compile time for pointers to global variables. But not for local variables. This certainly should be possible, as shown in this C code:

```c
void foo() {
    int a[5];
    static ptrdiff_t d = &a[5] - &a[0];
}
```

This seams to works for both cases (pointers to locals/globals) where the distance is constant:

```
auto dl = llvmModule->getDataLayout();
if (auto diff = pointer1->getPointerOffsetFrom(pointer2, dl)) {
    std::cerr << "pointer1->getPointerOffsetFrom: ok\n";
    std::cerr << "in bytes: diff = " << diff.value() << "\n";
    std::cerr << "for pointer arithmetic: "
        << diff.value() / dl.getTypeAllocSize(llvmType) << "\n";
} else {
    std::cerr << "pointer1->getPointerOffsetFrom: failed\n";
}
```

Sorry for so many updates and edits. I now have to sort my mind and my code :D

Comment: Constant folding is the right way, because it gets to the heart of the matter. In IR, you don't know the address of a global object, or of anything. If constant folding is able to get produce a number from (a+c)-(c+d) where a and c are addresses and b and d are offsets, that must be because a=c and b and c are constants. Is it a problem for you if this returns a false positive when a and c are the same `alloca`?

Comment: Thanks. You mean `(a+b) - (c+d)` where `a` and `c` are for example addresses of local arrays? You are right then this expression also should be compile time constant. For example `int a[5]; static ptrdiff_t diff = &a[5] - &a[0]` is legal in C and `diff` is initialized the dimension of the array.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I use the code from my last code snippet (with the `llvm::ConstantFoldInstruction`) then constant folding fails when `pointer1` and `pointer2` point into an array on the stack. It also fails when both point to the same variable on the stack.